# Print from java in cmd

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I ran my program in Java by creating a jar (`myProg.jar`), and run it via the CMD:

```
myprog.jar myarguments.
```

The problem is that I want that the cmd will wait until the program would terminate, and would print all the `System.out.println` in my project.

Now, I run this command, and the program runs, but it immediately shows the line in CMD that I expected my next command, and doesn't print or wait until my program would terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -jar myprog.jar myarguments.
```

Because in Windows calling a program by its name simply executes it just like a double click would, it started myprog.jar in the background. The straightforward way to run a JAR file is by calling `java -jar jarfile.jar`.

To read more about the way JAR files work, you may refer to [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) in the Java tutorial.